# How to run liquibase changelogSyncSQL or changelogSync up to a tag and/or labels?

Tags: initialization, liquibase

I'm adding liquibase to an existing project where tables and data already exist. **I would like to know how I might limit the scope of `changelogSync[SQL]` to a subset of available changes.**

#### Background

I've run `liquibase generateChangeLog` to capture the current state and placed this into say `src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/V2021.04.13.00.00.00__init01.yaml`.

I've also added another changeset to cover some new requirements in a new file. Let's call it `src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/V2021.04.13.00.00.00__new-feature.yaml`.

I've added a main changelog file `src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml` with the following contents:

```yaml
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll:
      path: changes
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
```

I now want to ensure that when I run `liquibase changelogSync[SQL]` against a particular version of the db that the scope is limited to the first changelog init01, thereby allowing from that point on a `liquibase update` or `updateToTag` et al, to continue with changes following init01.

I'm surprised to see that the `changelogSync[SQL]` commands don't seem to offer some way (that I can see from the [docs](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/changelogsync.html) for how to do this.

Besides printing the SQL and manually changing it, is there something I've missed? Any suggested approaches welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, the only solution I've found is to generate the SQL and then manually edit its contents to filter the change sets which don't correspond to your current schema.

Then you can apply the sql to the db.

Answer (score 2):

What about changelogSyncToTagSQL ?
Wouldn't it cover your needs?

Or maybe you could try changelogSyncSQL with additional parameters "label" or and "context" ?

[changelogSyncToTagSQL](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/changelogsynctotagsql.html)

[context](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/contexts.html?Highlight=context)

[labels](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/labels.html?Highlight=labels)

Comment: Yes I see that changelogSyncToTag and changelogSyncToTagSQL was added in liquibase 4.3.2 which was exactly what I was after. I was running 4.3.1.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)